# Private functions in Python Toolbox

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox

Is it OK to have private functions in a python toolbox?

I know it's possible because I tried. But I don't know if that's OK, I haven't seen anything in the Internet where someone from ESIR is using private functions.

Example:

```
class Toolbox():
 ....

class Tool():
 ....
  def ____clip_features____(self):
  # clip features

  def ____buffer_clipped_features____(self):
  # buffer
```

Basically I don't want to have all the code in Execute, I want to break it into functions.

Comment: "ESIR"?  Do you mean Esri?

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can split your code out into functions. Don't bother with private methods, they [aren't really private](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/private_functions.html) and they just make your code harder to read. Note that the convention for private methods is two underscores at the beginning of the variable name and none at the end.

However, you still need to have an `execute` method from which you call your other methods, otherwise ArcGIS won't be able to run the tool.